# How to get the row access policy related metadata using bigquery sql in Google Big Query?

Tags: google-bigquery

Google Big Query has well documented ways to get the metadata about other objects [(Table, Datasets, Routine, etc)](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-intro) using SQL like queries. I am using Python driver to execute those queries and getting expected result.
But I didn't found any query which can list the metadata about row access policies.

```
CREATE ROW ACCESS POLICY My_row_filter ON example_dataset.my_base_table3 GRANT TO ("domain:example.com") FILTER USING (lastName="Doe");
```

I have gone through the documentation and found the same can be displayed using bq command line tool.

```
bq ls --row_access_policies example_dataset.my_base_table3
```

Is there a way to get metadata related to row access policy via Python driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your search is right, **there is no** [**DQL**](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-ddl-dql-dml-dcl-tcl-commands/) to Row-access police, as you can see in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-row-level-security#listing_a_tables_row-level_access_policies).

Also, if you check the [Python Api for Bigquery](https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery), you will notice that this method to access the `rowAccessPolicies` is also **not implemented.**

**Ways to go:**

- Open a `feature request` [issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)
- While you dont have the feature, implement it on python by yourself using the BigQuery provided API, [here is how to use this method](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/rowAccessPolicies/list):

Basically you will have to make the proper authentication and a request to the API, like this:

*(This is not the full code, just a way to go, please implement it properly)*

```py
import requests
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError

url = 'https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/{projectId}/datasets/{datasetId}/tables/{tableId}/rowAccessPolicies'

try:
   response = requests.get(url)
   response.raise_for_status()
   print(response.content)
except HTTPError as http_err:
   print(f'HTTP error occurred: {http_err}')
```

Comment: Yes, it was helpful to know about the feature. I was also considering doing the REST API request for fetching. The code sample is greatly appreciated.